# Solaris /dev/poll support in Perl

Tags: perl, solaris, epoll

Has anyone any experience using /dev/poll (the Solaris equivalent of the Linux epoll method) with Perl, either via a module or directly in their application?

There's not much about this subject I can find through Google.

Comment: I should add that I'm interested in specifically doing ordinary TCP socket I/O asynchronously, replacing a busy `select()` call that is handling hundreds of file descriptors.

Answer (score 2):

If `/dev/poll` is exposed through the `poll` system call, try [`EV`](http://p3rl.org/libev#FEATURES).

Comment: Looks interesting. Not exactly sure how I'd use this but I'll look into it.